# Listener CheckBox

Tags: javascript, html

Estoy realizando un js que responde a al momento de hacer click en un checkbox:

```
function actionCheckbox(){
    var chkAp = document.getElementById("ahorroAP");
    var chkCa2 = document.getElementById("ahorroCa2");
    var chkAhorro = document.getElementById("ahorroDep");

    if(chkApv.value){
        agregarAp();    
    }else if(chkCta2.value){
        agregarPlanCa2();
    }else if(chkAhorroDeposito.value){
        agregarAhorroDep();
    }else{
        cleanfields();
    }           
}
```

El problema es que cuando hago click en el segundo chkbox ahorroCa2, se ejecuta solo el primer `if`.

**Objetivo**

Mi objetivo es hacer un listener que obtenga el evento click de cualquiera de esos 3 checkbox para que se ejecute el `if` que corresponde.

Comment: Así como esta tu pregunta el error es irreproducible. Intenta crear un [mcve].

Comment: El nombre de las variables que has creado y las que evalúas en los `if` son diferentes. ¿Así debe ser?

Answer (score 1):

Puedes probar con eso, ya que necesitas que cualquiera de esos 3 checkbox, el ultimo `else` lo veo innecesario.

```js
function handleClick(cb) {
  if(cb.id == 'ahorroAP' && cb.checked){
    //agregarAp(); 
     console.log("primer checkbox");
  } else if(cb.id == 'ahorroCa2' && cb.checked){
   //agregarPlanCa2();
     console.log("segundo checkbox");
  } else if(cb.id == 'ahorroDep' && cb.checked){
    //agregarAhorroDep();
     console.log("tercer checkbox");
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" onclick='handleClick(this);'  id="ahorroAP"> ahorroAP<br>
<input type="checkbox" onclick='handleClick(this);'  id="ahorroCa2"> ahorroCa2<br>
<input type="checkbox" onclick='handleClick(this);'  id="ahorroDep"> ahorroDep<br>
```

Answer (score 1):

La respuesta de el usuario siosi es valida y funcional pero si quisieras solucionarlo sin modificar tu markup podrias hacerlo de la siguiente forma:

```
function actionCheckbox(){
    var chkAp = document.getElementById("ahorroAP");
    var chkCa2 = document.getElementById("ahorroCa2");
    var chkAhorro = document.getElementById("ahorroDep");

    if(chkAp.checked){
        agregarAp();    
    }else if(chkCa2.checked){
        agregarPlanCa2();
    }else if(chkAhorro.checked){
        agregarAhorroDep();
    }else{
        cleanfields();
    }           
}
```

En caso de que quieras que esto funcione para mas de un checkbox a la vez deberias modificar los condicionales de la siguiente forma:

```
function actionCheckbox(){
    var chkAp = document.getElementById("ahorroAP");
    var chkCa2 = document.getElementById("ahorroCa2");
    var chkAhorro = document.getElementById("ahorroDep");
    var executed = false;
    if(chkAp.checked){
        agregarAp();    
        executed = true;
    }
    if(chkCa2.checked){
        agregarPlanCa2();
        executed = true;
    }
    if(chkAhorro.checked){
        agregarAhorroDep();
        executed = true;
    }

    if (executed == false){
        cleanfields();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Prueba agregando un manejador de eventos que obtenga el valor de id del objeto que inicio el evento, usar algo como

```
function eventHandler(evt) {
  let checkbox = evt.currentTarget.id;

  if(checkbox !== id) {
   //Tu condicion de id
 }
}
```